# How do I import an STL into pygltflib

Tags: python, 3d, gltf

How do I import an STL file as a mesh into pygltflib? I have tried `gltf = GLTF2().load(filename)` but that only accepts a valid gltf.

Comment: pygltf is a library specifically for parsing glTF files. An STL file is an entirely different format — you'll either need to convert the STL file to glTF beforehand, or use a library like [numpy-stl](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/)

Comment: Just to be clear. My answer demonstrates how to load (and potentially modify) a .stl file and then save it as a .gltf / .glb. "Import an STL file" is a pretty vague description, so I just assumed you wanted to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I used [pygltflib](https://gitlab.com/dodgyville/pygltflib) and [numpy-stl](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/) for this and it actually was not to hard, because .stl files typically meet these conditions:

1. Only consist of triplets of points / vertecies that make up a triangle
2. The order of the points does not matter, instead the face normals are stored
3. The STL consists of only one object
4. There are no colors or textures stored, just raw triangle meshes

With these ideas in mind I came up with a very basic implementation:

```py
import pygltflib
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
from math import sqrt

def normalize(vector):
    norm = 0
    for i in range(0, len(vector)):
        norm += vector[i] * vector [i]
    norm = sqrt(norm)
    for i in range(0, len(vector)):
        vector[i] = vector[i] / norm

    return vector

stl_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('cube.stl')

stl_points = []
for i in range(0, len(stl_mesh.points)): # Convert points into correct numpy array
    stl_points.append([stl_mesh.points[i][0],stl_mesh.points[i][1],stl_mesh.points[i][2]])
    stl_points.append([stl_mesh.points[i][3],stl_mesh.points[i][4],stl_mesh.points[i][5]])
    stl_points.append([stl_mesh.points[i][6],stl_mesh.points[i][7],stl_mesh.points[i][8]])

points = np.array(
    stl_points,
    dtype="float32",
)

stl_normals = []
for i in range(0, len(stl_mesh.normals)): # Convert points into correct numpy array
    normal_vector = [stl_mesh.normals[i][0],stl_mesh.normals[i][1],stl_mesh.normals[i][2]]
    normal_vector = normalize(normal_vector)
    stl_normals.append(normal_vector)
    stl_normals.append(normal_vector)
    stl_normals.append(normal_vector)

normals = np.array(
    stl_normals,
    dtype="float32"
)

points_binary_blob = points.tobytes()
normals_binary_blob = normals.tobytes()

gltf = pygltflib.GLTF2(
    scene=0,
    scenes=[pygltflib.Scene(nodes=[0])],
    nodes=[pygltflib.Node(mesh=0)],
    meshes=[
        pygltflib.Mesh(
            primitives=[
                pygltflib.Primitive(
                    attributes=pygltflib.Attributes(POSITION=0, NORMAL=1), indices=None
                )
            ]
        )
    ],
    accessors=[
        pygltflib.Accessor(
            bufferView=0,
            componentType=pygltflib.FLOAT,
            count=len(points),
            type=pygltflib.VEC3,
            max=points.max(axis=0).tolist(),
            min=points.min(axis=0).tolist(),
        ),
        pygltflib.Accessor(
            bufferView=1,
            componentType=pygltflib.FLOAT,
            count=len(normals),
            type=pygltflib.VEC3,
            max=None,
            min=None,
        ),
    ],
    bufferViews=[
        pygltflib.BufferView(
            buffer=0,
            byteOffset=0,
            byteLength=len(points_binary_blob),
            target=pygltflib.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        ),
        pygltflib.BufferView(
            buffer=0,
            byteOffset=len(points_binary_blob),
            byteLength=len(normals_binary_blob),
            target=pygltflib.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        ),
    ],
    buffers=[
        pygltflib.Buffer(
            byteLength=len(points_binary_blob) + len(normals_binary_blob)
        )
    ],
)
gltf.set_binary_blob(points_binary_blob + normals_binary_blob)
gltf.save("converted.glb")
```

I tested this with ASCII encoded .stl files generated in [OpenSCAD](https://www.openscad.org/), that can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/FrankenApps/c5d716ed5f8ed34bf260e12da10caf61).

The first part, was converting the points and normals from `numpy-stl`'s array layout, to the kind of array accepted by `pygltflib`. From there on it's just basic working with the `pygltflib`, to build the corresponding .gltf file.

### Issues

The code has currently one small Issue.

1. The models come out rotated

Fixing that should be easy, you would only have to apply a [coordinate transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) to the points and normals. But because the model can be rotated in space freely nevertheless I did not bother to fix this.

### Limitations

There are also some limitations, that could not easily be overcome. For example if you would like to assign different materials to different parts of the .stl this can not work, because there is quite literally no information about what a *part* is. Using only a single texture / color for the model is simple, though.

Comment: If you are wondering what the `normalize` function is about, look up the previous versions of this answer, before the latest **edit**.