# How to convert multiple stl files to one glb file with pygltflib

Tags: python, gltf

I started from this answer that I found on the site ([How do I import an STL into pygltflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341118/how-do-i-import-an-stl-into-pygltflib)). I wanted to know if it possible to take two or more stl files and merge them into one glb. I have not found much about it, also I have tried to modify the code in the link but with poor results. Does anyone have any advice or path to follow? Thanks in advance